# JSONP Request not rendering out, keep getting errors

Tags: javascript, json

Can anyone help with this JSONP Rendering to HTML, The request is in the source code however I keep getting errors on the foreach line.

Any help appreciated.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>



<div clas="main" >
<? php>

$jsondata = file_get_contents ("http://apis.leicestershirecommunity.com/api/planning/search?    output=jsonp&BBOX=");
$json = json_decode($jsondata,true);
$output = "<ul>";
foreach($json['items'] as $item) {

$output .= "<li><h2><a href=".$item['url'].">".$item['title']."</h2>    </a>





            </a>
            <br />

                </li>";


}
$output .= "</ul>";
echo $output;


?>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JSONP is not json. It's actual javascript code. The response from that jsonp server will literally look like this:

```
someFunctionCall({"json":"data","goes":"here"});
```

You need to strip off the javascript portion to expose the pure json, which means `someFunctionCall(` and `);`. What that looks like in your particular case, you'll have to figure out on your own.

And you get errors because your code simple assumes that nothing could ever go wrong. Exactly the wrong attitude. Never assume success when dealing with external resources. Always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: I've figured it out - I took the p out of the output=jsonp
http://davejkane.co.uk/api/json.php

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out - I took the p out of the output=jsonp